# Garbled text within XML file

Tags: xml

I'm trying to open a file that stores drum kit information. The format is called .mxgrp. When I open the file with a text editor, it looks like this, and repeats this way down the file. I am missing key info to make the file usable, and think it may be within the garbled portion. How can I make the entire file readable?

```
-in-#NI#CS#Document##NI#SoundShell#Sound#êatad rggenonHHcoamcoam  oa  oadisodiso¿ cwa cwa  wa  wadisodiso¿disodiso¡  WA CWA  OA  oa  oadisodiso¬ cwa cwa CWA  OA  oa  oadisodiso√ cwa cwa CWA  OACOAMciamciam  ia  iadisodiso¡ cwa cwa  wa  wadisodiso¿disodiso¡  WA CWA  IACIAM RGGatadofnienonNN<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<soundinfo version="400">

  <properties>
    <name>808 Kit</name>
  </properties>

  <banks>
    <bank>Kits</bank>
  </banks>

  <attributes>
    <attribute>
      <value>Analog Kit</value>
      <user-set>GB.Type</user-set>
    </attribute>
  </attributes>

</soundinfo>
atadOFNIenonatadomegenonOMEGatadtsrpenonéé pfd pfd cap cap CAP crp crp prp prp  rv  rv irv irvtcsg  tv  tv  RV PRP prp prp  rv  rv irv irvdesg  tv  tv  RV PRP prp prp  rv  rv irv irvspsg  tv  tv  RV PRP prp prp  rv  rv irv irvsvap  tv  tv  RV PRP prp prp  rv  rv irv irvteat  tv  tv  RV PRP CRP PFDTSRPatadTSRPenonatadcdomenonCDOMatadCDOMenonatadOMEGenonatadyqrbenonRRJ<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<query version="1">
```

Comment: What language are you using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to read in C# with this code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = 
                "-in-#NI#CS#Document##NI#SoundShell#Sound#êatad rggenonHHcoamcoam  oa  oadisodiso¿ cwa cwa  wa  wadisodiso¿disodiso¡  WA CWA  OA  oa  oadisodiso¬ cwa cwa CWA  OA  oa  oadisodiso√ cwa cwa CWA  OACOAMciamciam  ia  iadisodiso¡ cwa cwa  wa  wadisodiso¿disodiso¡  WA CWA  IACIAM RGGatadofnienonNN<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\" ?>\n" +
                "<soundinfo version=\"400\">\n" +
                                    "\n" +
                  "<properties>\n" +
                    "<name>808 Kit</name>\n" +
                  "</properties>\n" +
                                      "\n" +
                  "<banks>\n" +
                    "<bank>Kits</bank>\n" +
                  "</banks>\n" +
                                      "\n" +
                  "<attributes>\n" +
                    "<attribute>\n" +
                      "<value>Analog Kit</value>\n" +
                      "<user-set>GB.Type</user-set>\n" +
                    "</attribute>\n" +
                  "</attributes>\n" +
                                      "\n" +
                "</soundinfo>\n" +
                "atadOFNIenonatadomegenonOMEGatadtsrpenonéé pfd pfd cap cap CAP crp crp prp prp  rv  rv irv irvtcsg  tv  tv  RV PRP prp prp  rv  rv irv irvdesg  tv  tv  RV PRP prp prp  rv  rv irv irvspsg  tv  tv  RV PRP prp prp  rv  rv irv irvsvap  tv  tv  RV PRP prp prp  rv  rv irv irvteat  tv  tv  RV PRP CRP PFDTSRPatadTSRPenonatadcdomenonCDOMatadCDOMenonatadOMEGenonatadyqrbenonRRJ<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\" ?>\n" +
                "<query version=\"1\">\n" +
                "</query>";

            StringReader reader = new StringReader(input);
            string inputLine = "";
            string XML = "";
            while((inputLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                inputLine = inputLine.Trim();
                if(inputLine.Length > 0)
                {
                    if(inputLine.StartsWith("<"))
                    {
                        XML += inputLine;
                    }
                }
            }
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            XML = "<Root>" + XML + "</Root>"; 
            doc.LoadXml(XML);
        }
    }
}
​
```